# Attach an Image to a email button

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to attach an image .png to an email 
Anyone can tell me what Am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance....

```
    var myUIImage : UIImage!
        @IBAction func shareThisApp(sender: AnyObject) {  
            let mailComposeViewController = ShareAppEmail()
            if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

//self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

//The line below is showing Error: fatal error: unexpected found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myUIImage)

            mailComposeViewController.addAttachmentData(imageData!, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "image.png")
            } else {
                self.showSendMailErrorAlert()

//self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        func ShareAppEmail() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
            let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self 

            mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([""])
            mailComposerVC.setSubject("Check this great app")
            mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Take a look at this new app", isHTML: false)

            return mailComposerVC
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code now looks correct except couple things. First: you should leave self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) line and put it after attaching image to mailComposeViewController - you still need to display this controller. Second: the reason you're getting error is you haven't set value to myUIImage and trying to unwrap this value implicitly using "!" sign. If property can be nil use optional type instead. I mean myUIImage property should be UIImage? instead of UIImage! and then check if image is set up should be implemented. So final version of your code should be something like this:

```
var myImage: UIImage?
@IBAction func shareThisApp(sender: AnyObject) {  
    let mailComposeViewController = ShareAppEmail()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
         if let myImage = myImage,
            let myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage) {
             mailComposeViewController.addAttachmentData(myImageData, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "image.png")
             presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
         } else {
             // myImage is not set or have wrong format
         }
   } else {
       self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
   }
}
// dropping func ShareAppEmail() cause everything seems correct there
```

Comment: @lyuna just update the question as you suggested, the errors are gone, but I still can not see the picture in the email body. :( Any other suggestion? tks

Comment: Eddie, you're displaying mailComposeViewController in both cases if the current device is able to send email or not. According Apple documentation you "must not display the mail composition interface" if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() returns you false. Besides you're adding image attachment only in case device *is not able to* send emails. Move image adding code before presenting mailComposeViewController in MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() true condition and you'll see your image attachment.

Comment: @lyuna thank you for the explanation lyuna, I tried to follow your suggestion but my knowledge is limited in Swift, please if you have time take a look in the modifications I made if is correct, anyway is not correct or I would have the picture on the email body. I got an error that is explained in the code. Cheers

Comment: Just updated  my answer. Please, take a look and ask questions if something remains unclear for you.

Comment: @lyuna I am really sorry, now there is no errors but at button pressed it does nothing. Do I have to write something after the first else? I see you comment but ... :(

Comment: Eddie, you can write there like print("Image is not set up") and if you see this text in console while tapping the button that would mean that you haven't assigned image to myImage before presenting mail composer.  Also add showSendMailErrorAlert method implementation to your question please.

Comment: ups I got it, I have not assigned the image to my Image :( Thank you for your help lyuna :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't yet set what mailComposerVC is - you're telling your code to use a line that hasn't yet been defined.  Since Swift 1.2, you have to define what a constant is before you can use it.  Try moving your let... statement further up in your code, or using a constant you defined earlier.